# Simple swagger specification, to retrieve an html web page

Tags: swagger

I'm new to swagger, and I'm trying to make a very simple specification, with only a get method in order to retrieve a web page, this is the code:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "example",
    "description": "Sample api to retrieve a web page.",
    "version": "0.1"
  },
  "host":"example.org", #"localhost:8080",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/":{
      "get":{
        "summary":"Return the web page.",
        "description":"",
        "produces":["text/html"],
        "responses":{
          "200":{
            "description":"OK",
          },
              "400":{
                "description":"Bad request"
              },
              "404":{
                "description":"Not Found"
              }
            }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

I'm using the swagger online editor.

Unfortunately when I execute the request, it did not return the web page and no one of the status code that I have implemented in the specification, it return me in the detail section the error:

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

Someone can tell me where I'm wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "Try it out" button to work in the [Swagger online editor](http://editor.swagger.io), your API endpoints must be [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)-enabled. That is, your server (`example.org` or `localhost:8080`) must be configured to return certain response headers that would allow editor.swagger.io to make cross-domain requests to your server. This is explained in more details here:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#cors-support

The way to configure CORS depends on the server/framework used to host the app. This page has instructions for some common web servers:
https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Thank you, I have followed your suggestion and now it works!

Comment: Is it possible to disable CORS for the "Try it button"?

Comment: @SimCor: CORS is enforced by browsers as a security measure, so it cannot be disabled on the server side or from web pages. Some browsers provide a way to disable CORS for temporary testing - this will only affect _your browser_. For example, if you use Chrome launch it with these arguments: `chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=<some folder>`.